# What will be the best way to Visualize the following data?

Tags: plot, data-visualization, distribution, data-science, data-analysis

what will be the best way to show the difference between the distance points with the timestamps on the plot? or what kind of distributional chart will be suitable in this case? because I have thousand points with multiple ID's can't just go through the whole data.

Example:

```
ID   DateTIme                 Distance
1   2011-01-23 00:56:59       0.452323
1   2011-01-23 00:57:00       0.746908
1   2011-01-23 00:57:00       0.945455
1   2011-01-23 00:58:00       0.456253
2   2011-01-23 00:42:00       0.098822
2   2011-01-23 00:43:00       0.156353
2   2011-01-23 00:44:00       0.001271
2   2011-01-23 00:44:59       0.766617
3   2011-01-23 00:55:00       0.198188
3   2011-01-23 00:56:00       0.009182
3   2011-01-23 00:57:00       0.167261
3   2011-01-23 00:57:59       0.126766
```

please just mention the ideas? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you're mainly interesting in variable within ID, then ignore the timestamp and show the data by ID:

[image]

If the times are important, too, you can put time on the X and try color for each ID.

[image]

But color doesn't scale past 10 or more colors. In that case you could make a small graph for each ID or use a unique shape for each ID's dots.

Comment: I thought of it, but when there are 1000 of ids, it becomes clutter, you won't understand what's going on

Answer (score 1):

A bar graph with the time stamps grouped under each bar with a each bar having values of two distance's and they will encompass anything between those. Almost any kind of graph would work, come to think of it, but I believe that the bar graph works best.  In case this isn't clear, what I"m saying is to divide your timestamps into groups by their distance's and then to set up a graph which shows which timestamps belong with the closet bar on the graph (by distance). Ex.
[Example Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zCou.png)

Edit: Sorry, but I do not know if this will be helpful because I do not know the context of why you need this graph. Did my best.

Edit2: The ID's are (*as far as I can see) irrelevant to the distance-to-timestamp relationship, so if you want to throw the ID next to wherever you show the timestamps that should be fine.